# Create PLSQL package on linked database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database

I have two databases. One which contains the packages and is always available. And another one that stores the data and is rebuild every day.

The packages on the first database are making queries on the second. Now I have queries, which need themselves some functions. I got a star schema on the second and sometimes I need a select which includes all details in on row.
Something like `SELECT getDetails(Master-pk) FROM xyz WHERE abc;`

The function `getDetails(pk)` would get all the Details for this key and return them in one string: like 'detail1, detail2, ...'

Because of the performance I can not put these functions on the database where the other packages are, but have to put them on the database which is rebuild every day.

So I want to create the package each time, before I start the queries. Locally this works fine with `DBMS_SQL.parse(curID, VARCHAR2<b>A</b>, first, last, 1);`
But the `DBMS_SQL.parse@DBLink(..)` does give me a PLS-306. Wrong number or type of parameter.

My restrictions are:

1. I can not include the package in any start script or what so ever.
2. The package must be available on the second DB. 
   No: `dbms_sql.parse(id, 'SELECT getDetails@firstDB(pk) FROM..',1);` 
   Would not perform well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Create a synonym for the remote package.  Something like

```
create synonym remote_dbms_sql for dbms_sql@db_link
/
```

then you should be able to execute this locally:

```
remote_dbms_sql.parse(curID, VARCHAR2<b>A</b>, first, last, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Have tried it, but the same exception is raised.